# why Scrollview and child view size is inconsistent sometimes

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, height, ios-autolayout

I have a scrollview and a child view.

Child view size increases dynamically depending on its content.

I am programatically changing the child view height via constraint and at the same time I am incrementing scrollview content size . so the scrolllview I can scroll to see the complete child view.

for example if I am setting child view 320 px .. I can see the child view size has become more than 320 px .. sometime its like 500 px(both scrollview content size and child view height) or something ... sometimes its 320px as I had set.

this seems ridiculous to me

is this something to do with xamarin.ios ? or Am I doing something wrong ?

I am changing the view height on ...

Viewwilllayoutsubview and I'm changing the view height before I call 
*this.View.LayoutIfNeeded*

can somebody explain me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Could you please share related codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIScrollView has to fill the view, I added image for UIScrollView's constraints [image: UIScrollView's constraints]

and as you now if child views height is longer than UIScrollView starts scroll but

1. inner Childview's constraints should look like that. (height can increase dynamically as you said)

[image]

2. in your ViewController, you should ping you UIScrollView and update its Content size.

> ```
>   public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews(){ 
>
>    base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews(); 
>     ScrlView.ContentSize = VwContent.Frame.Size;
>
>    }
> ```